# Converting dictionary value to string

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary, nmap

Im dealing with the output from the Nmap scripting engine and I'm having trouble with string conversions.

The result from nmap places it in a dictionary, that I convert to a string:

```
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
sslNmapOutput = nm.scan(hosts='192.168.2.50', arguments='--script ssl-enum-ciphers -p443')

sslOutput = ', '.join("%s=%s" % (key,val) for (key,val) in sslNmapOutput.iteritems())

resultString = re.search("warnings:(.*)SHA1\n", sslOutput)
resultString = result.group(1)
print sslOutput.strip()
```

This prints the following:

```
nmap={'scanstats': {'uphosts': '1', 'timestr': 'Wed Mar 15 17:59:42 2017', 'downhosts': '0', 'totalhosts': '1', 'elapsed': '18.85'}, 'scaninfo': {'tcp': {'services': '443', 'method': 'syn'}}, 'command_line': 'nmap -oX - --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p443
192.168.2.50'}, scan={'192.168.2.50': {'status': {'state': 'up', 'reason': 'reset'}, 'hostnames': [{'type': '', 'name': ''}], 'vendor': {}, 'addresses': {'ipv4': '192.168.2.50'}, 'tcp': {443: {'product': '', 'state': 'open', 'version': '', 'name': 'https', 'conf': '3', 'script': {'ssl-enum-ciphers': '\n  SSLv3: \n    ciphers: \n      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (secp256r1) - C\n      TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - C\n      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A\n      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A\n      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A\n      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A\n      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A\n      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A\n      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - C\n      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - C\n      TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C\n    compressors: \n      NULL\n    cipher preference: server\n    warnings: \n      64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack\n      Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465\n      CBC-mode cipher in SSLv3 (CVE-2014-3566)\n      Weak certificate signature: SHA1\n }, 'extrainfo': '', 'reason': 'syn-ack', 'cpe': ''}}}}
```

**I want to get all the information between `warnings:` and `SHA1\n`. However, when I then print the result of the regular expression, I get the following:**

```
\n      64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack\n      Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465\n      CBC-mode cipher in SSLv3 (CVE-2014-3566)\n      Weak certificate signature:
```

**What I want is for the value to be printed as it would appear with the correct indentation of whitespace and newlines, like the following:**

```
test =  "\n      64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack\n      Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465\n      CBC-mode cipher in SSLv3 (CVE-2014-3566)\n      Weak certificate signature: "
print test.strip()
```

Output:

```
64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
CBC-mode cipher in SSLv3 (CVE-2014-3566)
Weak certificate signature:
```

Comment: Look at the [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module.

Comment: Use `json.dumps` to convert dictionary to string and then use `pprint`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo of what's happened:

```
>>> s = 'a\nb'
>>> print s
a
b
>>> print {'key': s}
{'key': 'a\nb'}
```

`sslNmapOutput` is a dictionary with a value deep down in the tree that contains actual newline characters. Calling `str` (via the `%s`) on the immediate values which are themselves dictionaries creates a string representation where the newline characters in inner values get replaced by the two characters `\n`. Don't apply the regex to `sslOutput`. Rather apply it to the original string contained in `sslNmapOutput`, which in this case is available as:

```
sslNmapOutput['scan']['192.168.2.50']['tcp'][443]['script']['ssl-enum-ciphers']
```

Comment: I've tried applying the regex to `sslNmapOutput` with `result = re.search("warnings:(.*)SHA1\n", str(sslNmapOutput))`. However, that still comes back with the newline char's when printing. How would I specify, the `['ssl-enum-ciphers'] part of it?

Comment: @Papantonia `re.search("warnings:(.*)SHA1\n", sslNmapOutput['scan']['192.168.2.50']['tcp'][443]['script']['ssl-enum-ciphers'])`.